# How to delete a row gridview/configure data Source which made from multiple tables .net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I made a gridview which shows

OneAlbumID, Price, Condition, AlbumName.

by using configure data source

which is  View, I made on  Microsoft SQL

```
SELECT        dbo.OneAlbum.OneAlbumID, dbo.Albums.AlbumName, dbo.Conditions.Condition, dbo.OneAlbum.Price
FROM            dbo.OneAlbum INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Conditions ON dbo.OneAlbum.ConditionID = dbo.Conditions.ConditionID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Albums ON dbo.OneAlbum.AlbumID = dbo.Albums.AlbumID
```

by joing these tables

OneAlbum-------------------------------------------------------------

OneAlbumID   Primary key,

Price,

ConditionID  Foreign key,

AlbumID      Foreign Key

Albums---------------------------------------------------------------------

AlbumID   Primary Key,

AlbumName

Condition----------------------------------------------------------------------

ConditionID  Primary Key,

Condition

I try to delete a row on this gridview

I made a code on configure data source like this, which is not working

```
DELETE FROM  [View_OneAlbums] WHERE (OneAlbumID = GridView1.SelectedValue)
```

the error says

> The multi-part identifier "GridView1.SelectedValue" could not be
>   bound. View or function 'View_OneAlbums' is not updatable because the
>   modification affects multiple base tables.

how can I make/design codes to delete a row form this gridview by using Configure Data Source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you can't delete records from a DB View, as they are simply a way to visualize data, not meant for editing it.

Second, you need to know exactly what you want to delete and where that data is located within the tables referred in your view.

If you only want to remove that specific row from the `GridView` (if you phrased your question correctly), Grids have built-in functions to remove certain items from the dataset that was loaded on them. Know that this will only remove from the Grid, not the DB View itself

Comment: Oh and by the way, MySQL is Oracle not Microsoft, according to the tags you used